# Unable to Parse XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse a large xml file (more than 50mb). Getting the following parsing error. 
File attached for reference. [File](https://www.davidjones.com/googleproductfeed.xml)

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('input_file.xml')
```

```
error
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: no element found: line 21, column 0
```

Comment: The obvious answer is that the file does indeed have an error.  The error message even helpfully points out the line number.  Have you inspected the file to see for yourself?

Comment: @Ahmad Hasnain, please add XML code of line  20 to 30

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The file is too big and unable to load in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not well-formed, ElementTree cannot parse it. Please take look at your XML file and check whether it has a proper closing tag, maybe special characters and other stuff.

Comment: The file is too big to be opened and inspected in a browser. None of the free xml parsers could load it either.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html